# Tesseract unable to copy data to SD?

Tags: java, android, ocr, android-sdcard, tesseract

I think I'm doing something wrong with my paths but I can't figure out what. I am testing on a Nexus 7 if that's relevant. Following examples I tried to copy the tessdata folder over to the SD card however it keeps telling me unable to copy file not found. I don't quite understand why. (I have the tesseract project as a library and I have the tessdata folder copied into assets).
All help is appreciated thanks!

Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private static ImageView imageView;
        // protected static Bitmap bit;
        protected static Bitmap mImageBitmap;
        // protected static String DATA_PATH;
        public static final String STORAGE_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/rjb";
        protected static String tesspath = STORAGE_PATH + "/tessdata";
        protected static String savepath = null;
        protected static String TAG = "OCR";
        protected static String lang = "eng";

        // main method
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                // This is my image view for to show the image with
                imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                // this is the take a photo button
                Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);

                //check if the rjb directory is there
                //make it if its not
                createmydir();

                //if (!(new File(STORAGE_PATH + File.separator + "tessdata" + File.separator + lang + ".traineddata")).exists()) {
                        try {
                                AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
                                //open the asset manager and open the traineddata path
                                InputStream in = assetManager.open("tessdata/eng.traineddata");
                                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tesspath + "/eng.traineddata");
                                byte[] buf = new byte[8024];
                                int len;
                                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                                        out.write(buf, 0, len);
                                }
                                in.close();
                                out.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                android.util.Log.e(TAG, "Was unable to copy " + lang
                                                + " traineddata " + e.toString());
                                android.util.Log.e(TAG, "IM PRINTING THE STACK TRACE");
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                //} else {
                        processImage(STORAGE_PATH + File.separator + "savedAndroid.jpg");
                //}
                photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                // CALL THE PICTURE (this works)
                                dispatchTakePictureIntent(0);
                        }
                });
        }

        private void createmydir() {
                File t = new File(STORAGE_PATH);

                if(t.exists()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IM TOASTIN CAUSE IT EXISTS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {

                        t.mkdirs();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IM TOASTIN CUZ I MADE IT EXIST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        }

        private void handleSmallCameraPhoto(Intent intent) {
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                imageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 4;

                saveImageAndroid(mImageBitmap);

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(savepath, options);
                ExifInterface exif;
                try {
                        exif = new ExifInterface(savepath);
                        int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
                        int rotate = 0;
                        switch (exifOrientation) {
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                                rotate = 90;
                                break;
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                                rotate = 180;
                                break;
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                                rotate = 270;
                                break;
                        }
                        if (rotate != 0) {
                                int w = bitmap.getWidth();
                                int h = bitmap.getHeight();
                                // Setting pre rotate
                                Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
                                mtx.preRotate(rotate);
                                // Rotating Bitmap & convert to ARGB_8888, required by tess
                                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, false);
                                bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
                        }



                        // DATA_PATH = getDataPath();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                handleSmallCameraPhoto(data);
        }

        // write bitmap to storage
        // saves it as savedandroid.jpg
        // saves location in savepath
        private void saveImageAndroid(final Bitmap passedBitmap) {
                try {
                        savepath = STORAGE_PATH + File.separator + "savedAndroid.jpg";
                        FileOutputStream mFileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(savepath);
                        passedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,mFileOutStream);
                        mFileOutStream.flush();
                        mFileOutStream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(int actionCode) {
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);
        }

        private void processImage(final String filePath) {
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 2;
                options.inPurgeable = true;
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
                if (bitmap != null) {
                        /*
                         * was for rotating but no longer needed int width =
                         * bitmap.getWidth(); int height = bitmap.getHeight(); Matrix matrix
                         * = new Matrix(); matrix.postRotate(rotation); bitmap =
                         * Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
                         * bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
                         */

                        TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
                        baseApi.setDebug(true);
                        baseApi.init(STORAGE_PATH, "eng");
                        baseApi.setPageSegMode(100);
                        baseApi.setPageSegMode(7);
                        baseApi.setImage(bitmap);
                        String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
                        android.util.Log.i(TAG, "recognizedText: 1 " + recognizedText);
                        baseApi.end();
                        if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase("eng")) {
                                recognizedText = recognizedText
                                                .replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", " ");
                        }
                        android.util.Log.i(TAG,
                                        "recognizedText: 2 " + recognizedText.trim());
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to place the files on sd card and just try simple ocr on an simple image like ear, if that works then go for copying the language files through program, because of that you may come to know where the error is.